# How can I create an iBook-style user interface?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios4, containers

I was working on storing some books or pdf in a shelf. Can i get some tutorial or code which helps in making Apple iBooks kind of a user interface. How can i implement this one?

Here is screenshot of what I mean:

[image]

Comment: I cannot help but wonder how many patents you would be violating ;-)

Comment: @ Martin Kristiansen:I just wanted to know how can it be implemented or anything similar of that kind..

Comment: You can use the Newsstand Kit framework to develop the client side of a Newsstand application. Through the Newsstand, users can browse through newspapers and magazines that are optimized for viewing on mobile devices.

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is a recreation of `UITableView` that can handle multiple columns per row.

You do this by subclassing `UIScrollView` and write **allot** of code.

I have done one such implementation called `CWColumnTableView`, with support for animations, drag-n-drop reordering and more. It's available under BSD-license here: https://github.com/Jayway/CWUIKit
The project also has an example application. Basically it works just as `UITableView`, you just provide your cells, and optionally a background and/or row backgrounds.

Comment: :hey the code u have given , i am not able to run or compile that one

Comment: @sujay: Have you followed the instructions in the `README` file?